# Pop multiple elements from a set

Tags: python, set

Is there a way in python to pop multiple elements from a set, without a for loop over the `pop` method and without converting the set to a list?

Comment: No. Why don't you want to use a for-loop? And what did you have in mind by converting to a list?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I can use slicing if I convert to a list, but in effect I would need a for loop nevertheless

Comment: Just to be clear: You are looking for an operation akin to ``removed = some_set.pop(n)``, which removes ``n`` elements from ``some_set`` and stores them in ``removed``?

Comment: @raffaem you will **always**, in effect, need a for-loop.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes. Where the `n` elements can be chones arbitrarily (not that there would be any other way, given that a set is not sorted)

Comment: Can you clarify your restriction on not using a loop? Even some magic ``.pop(n)`` method would be using a for loop behind the scenes.

Comment: Seriously, what's wrong with `for _ in range(n): myset.pop()`?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I thought that `stored = list(); for i in range(10); stored.append(myset.pop())` would be slower then `stored = myset.pop(10)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga (i) I would have to make a list `stored=list()` and append to it the elements I retrieve from the set one by one. Instead, if I retrieve 10 elements from a set at once, I have to call `list.append()` just one time (ii) I don't know, also, whether retrieving 10 elements at one time would be faster than retrieving 10 times one element by itself

Comment: @raffaem what? What you are saying doesn't make any sense. You would have to do all those things anyway. So what if you have to call `list.append`? You have these assumptions that are simply not true.

Comment: Just use ``[myset.pop() for _ in range(n)]``, then. If running that loop in Python instead of a builtin is the bottleneck of your application, you have other things to worry about.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Isn't calling `list.append()` one time faster than calling `list.append()` 10 times?

Comment: Yes, calling ``list.extend`` once is faster than ``list.append`` often. No, in practice this is *not* the bottleneck of your application. If you are worried about performance, did you benchmark your code yet? Are you absolutely sure that "pop in a loop" is the issue?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi well, `list.extend` basically just does `.append` in a loop, of course, the looping is done below the interpreter level, but really, that will be practically negligible

Comment: @raffaem well, *yes*, but *in all the cases you would have to call the equivalent of `.append`* for the total number of items in your list. You could pre-allocate a list, but that is almost never materially faster. Again, you seem to be under the impression that there is a magic way of doing things "in bulk".

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
import random

pop_count = 3

original_set -= set(random.sample(original_set, pop_count))
```

Comment: Why sample randomly? A set already has arbitrary order.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I thought perhaps "arbitrary" could mean in an unspecified manner (implementation-dependent manner). Which means,, whether it is random or not could be implementation-dependent

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
set = {"A", "B", "C", "D"} - {"A", "B"}
```

Comment: That presumes I would have "A" and "B" predefined, which I dont

Comment: So, how do you decide which elements to pop or remove?

Comment: at random is perfectly fine. A set is not ordered. I want 10 random elements popped out from the set

Comment: If so, I agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga - I don't believe you can do this without using a loop. Also, consider using a list rather than a set as it has an index attached.

Comment: @OmriShayo even *this* uses, in effect, a loop. The loop is just hidden. It is *really not possible to do this without, in effect, a loop*. But why do you suggest to use a `list`? What does having an index matter here?

Comment: I agree, however the loop is located inside the function, as you stated (no need for you to write it). And regarding the use of indexes, a random item may be selected (and popped) by using it

Comment: @OmriShayo *but that's exactly what `set.pop()` does* Basically, the fastest and most straightforward way for the OP to do what they want is `[myset.pop() for _ in range(n)]`

Comment: You're right. I thought the process worked the same as remove. I appreciate the explanation, thanks!